# django annotate with queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I have Users who take Surveys periodically. The system has multiple surveys which it issues at set intervals from the submitted date of the last issued survey of that particular type.

```py
class Survey(Model):
    name = CharField()
    description = TextField()
    interval = DurationField()  
    users = ManyToManyField(User, related_name='registered_surveys')
    ...

class SurveyRun(Model):
    ''' A users answers for 1 taken survey '''
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='runs')
    survey = ForeignKey(Survey, related_name='runs')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    # answers = ReverseForeignKey...
```

So with the models above a user should be alerted to take survey `A` next on this date:

```py
A.interval + SurveyRun.objects.filter(
    user=user, 
    survey=A
).latest('submitted').submitted
```

I want to run a daily periodic task which queries all users and creates new runs for all users who have a survey due according to this criteria:

For each survey the user is registered:

- if no runs exist for that user-survey combo then create the first run for that user-survey combination and alert the user
- if there are runs for that survey and none are open (an open run has been created but not submitted so `submitted=None`) and the latest one's submitted date plus the survey's interval is <= today, create a new run for that user-survey combo and alert the user

Ideally I could create a manager method which would annotate with a `surveys_due` field like:

```py
users_with_surveys_due = User.objects.with_surveys_due().filter(surveys_due__isnull=False)
```

Where the annotated field would be a queryset of `Survey` objects for which the user needs to submit a new round of answers.
And I could issue alerts like this:

```py
for user in users_with_surveys_due.all():
    for survey in user.surveys_due:
        new_run = SurveyRun.objects.create(
            user=user,
            survey=survey
        )
        alert_user(user, run)
```

However I would settle for a boolean flag annotation on the User object indicating one of the `registered_surveys` needs to create a new run.

How would I go about implementing something like this `with_surveys_due()` manager method so Postgres does all the heavy lifting? Is it possible to annotate with a collection objects, like a reverse FK?

UPDATE:

For clarity here is my current task in python:

```py
def make_new_runs_and_alert_users():
    runs = []
    Srun = apps.get_model('surveys', 'SurveyRun')
    for user in get_user_model().objects.prefetch_related('registered_surveys', 'runs').all():
        for srvy in user.registered_surveys.all():
            runs_for_srvy = user.runs.filter(survey=srvy)
            # no runs exist for this registered survey, create first run
            if not runs_for_srvy.exists():
                runs.append(Srun(user=user, survey=srvy))
                ...

            # check this survey has no open runs
            elif not runs_for_srvy.filter(submitted=None).exists():
                latest = runs_for_srvy.latest('submitted')
                if (latest.submitted + qnr.interval) <= timezone.now():
                    runs.append(Srun(user=user, survey=srvy))
    Srun.objects.bulk_create(runs)
```

UPDATE #2:

In attempting to use Dirk's solution I have this simple example:

```py
In [1]: test_user.runs.values_list('survey__name', 'submitted')                                                                                                                                     
Out[1]: <SurveyRunQuerySet [('Test', None)]>
In [2]: test_user.registered_surveys.values_list('name', flat=True)                                                                                                                                 
Out[2]: <SurveyQuerySet ['Test']>
```

The user has one open run (`submitted=None`) for the `Test` survey and is registered to one survey (`Test`). He/She should not be flagged for a new run seeing as there is an un-submitted run outstanding for the only survey he/she is registered for. So I create a function encapsulating the Dirk's solution called `get_users_with_runs_due`:

```py
In [10]: get_users_with_runs_due()                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[10]: <UserQuerySet [<User: test@gmail.com>]> . # <-- should be an empty queryset

In [107]: for user in _: 
              print(user.email, i.has_survey_due)  
test@gmail.com True  # <-- should be false
```

UPDATE #3:

In my previous update I had made some changes to the logic to properly match what I wanted but neglected to mention or show the changes. Here is the query function below with comments by the changes:

```py
def get_users_with_runs_due():
    today = timezone.now()

    survey_runs = SurveyRun.objects.filter(
        survey=OuterRef('pk'),
        user=OuterRef(OuterRef('pk'))
    ).order_by('-submitted')

    pending_survey_runs = survey_runs.filter(submitted__isnull=True)

    surveys = Survey.objects.filter(
        users=OuterRef('pk')
    ).annotate(
        latest_submission_date=Subquery(
            survey_runs.filter(submitted__isnull=False).values('submitted')[:1]
        )
    ).annotate(
        has_survey_runs=Exists(survey_runs)
    ).annotate(
        has_pending_runs=Exists(pending_survey_runs)
    ).filter(
        Q(has_survey_runs=False) | # either has no runs for this survey or
        ( # has no pending runs and submission date meets criteria
            Q(has_pending_runs=False, latest_submission_date__lte=today - F('interval'))
        )
    )

    return User.objects.annotate(has_survey_due=Exists(surveys)).filter(has_survey_due=True)
```

UPDATE #4:

I tried to isolate the issue by creating a function which would make most of the annotations on the Surveys by user in an attempt to check the annotation on that level prior to querying the User model with it.

```py
def annotate_surveys_for_user(user):
    today = timezone.now()

    survey_runs = SurveyRun.objects.filter(
        survey=OuterRef('pk'),
        user=user
    ).order_by('-submitted')

    pending_survey_runs = survey_runs.filter(submitted=None)

    return Survey.objects.filter(
            users=user
        ).annotate(
            latest_submission_date=Subquery(
                survey_runs.filter(submitted__isnull=False).values('submitted')[:1]
            )
        ).annotate(
            has_survey_runs=Exists(survey_runs)
        ).annotate(
            has_pending_runs=Exists(pending_survey_runs)
        )
```

This worked as expected. Where the annotations were accurate and filtering with:

```py
result.filter(
    Q(has_survey_runs=False) |
        (
           Q(has_pending_runs=False) &
           Q(latest_submission_date__lte=today - F('interval'))
        )
    )
```

produced the desired results: An empty queryset where the user should not have any runs due and vice-versa. Why is this not working when making it the subquery and querying from the User model?

Comment: Are you using postgreSQL?

Comment: @dirkgroten yes

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? One of the answer gives a reference to Subqueries but that's a relatively new feature.

Comment: @JulienKieffer 2.2

Comment: The query for `has_pending_runs` was checking for True instead instead of False, fixed that below.

Comment: @dirkgroten in my haste adding the update yesterday I failed to mention I had already made that change in the logic along with another one I have detailed above. It still fails for that case.

Answer (score 11):

To annotate users with whether or not they have a survey due, I'd suggest to use a [Subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Q, F, OuterRef, Subquery, Exists
from django.utils import timezone

today = timezone.now()

survey_runs = SurveyRun.objects.filter(survey=OuterRef('pk'), user=OuterRef(OuterRef('pk'))).order_by('-submitted')

pending_survey_runs = survey_runs.filter(submitted__isnull=True)

surveys = Survey.objects.filter(users=OuterRef('pk'))
   .annotate(latest_submission_date=Subquery(survey_runs.filter(submitted__isnull=False).values('submitted')[:1]))
   .annotate(has_survey_runs=Exists(survey_runs))
   .annotate(has_pending_runs=Exists(pending_survey_runs))
   .filter(Q(has_survey_runs=False) | Q(latest_submission_date__lte=today - F('interval')) & Q(has_pending_runs=False))

User.objects.annotate(has_survey_due=Exists(surveys))
    .filter(has_survey_due=True)
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to do the other one. You cannot annotate a queryset with another queryset, values must be field equivalents. Also you cannot use a `Subquery` as `queryset` parameter to `Prefetch`, unfortunately. But since you're using PostgreSQL you could use `ArrayField` to list the ids of the surveys in a wrapped value, but I haven't found a way to do that, as you can't use `aggregate` inside a `Subquery`.

Comment: getting `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Exists object`. I suspect its for this: `~Q(Exists(survey_runs))`. Can you use Q without specifying a field?

Comment: I made a test user with with 1 registered survey `A`: interval: 2 weeks, and 2 runs 'Run1': submitted: `2019-08-15 17:10:54.096004+00:00` and `Run2` submitted: `None` and this query annotated `has_survey_due` as `True`

Comment: what's the Run2 with submitted: none? That's a special case?

Comment: It's an open/ un-submitted run. I mentioned it in the second bullet point in my original post.

Comment: ah missed that. but that's easy to add. one sec

Comment: Still getting a false positive with that earlier test case. Give me a minute here so I can gather all the details. Can we move this to a chat once I have that together?

Comment: won't be online for the rest of the evening. back tomorrow. maybe you got some ideas with my answer and solve it yourself by then.

Comment: also added a filter in the first annotation, because null values for dates could mess up the ordering actually, might make a difference. I added the link to the docs so you see for yourself if there are more clues there.

Comment: added changes I made to the query I used in my earlier example in updates. The false positive remains.